# Pullback of a translation map of a divisor in Birkenhake-Lange's book "Complex Abelian Varieties"

Tags: divisors-algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, pullback

I'm currently studying the book 'Complex Abelian Varieties' by Birkenhake and Lange. On page 74, after lemma 1.5, the authors make the following statement:

'Another observation, which will prove useful on multiple occasions, is as follows: by definition, $t_x^*D = D - x$, which implies that $y \in t_x^*D$ if and only if $x \in t_y^*D$.

However, I'm having trouble understanding the equation $t_x^*D = D - x$. For instance, if we take $D = \sum n_p(p)$, it seems to me that the pullback of a translation by $x$ of the divisor should be $D = \sum n_p(p+x)$. Can someone clarify this for me?"

Comment: $D-x$ is a notation for $t_x^*D$. What you said is right; if $D=\sum n_p (p)$ then $D=\sum n_p (p+x)$. What they mean by $y\in t_x^*D$ is that $y$ belongs to the support of the divisor $t_x^* D$.

Comment: Thanks, daruma. In fact I've come to my own conclusion. Thank you for providing assurance. You can find further discussions on the following link : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454138/pullback-of-a-translation-map-of-a-divisor-in-birkenhake-langes-book-complex-a?noredirect=1#comment1175512_454138